# Number of possible inequalities for $n$ variables.

Tags: combinatorics, inequality

Let's say there are two variables $x$ and $y$. Here are the possible inequalities:

(i) $x<y$ 
(ii) $x>y$ 
(iii) $x=y$

So, there are $3$ possible inequalities. But let's say there are $n$ variables $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,\cdots,x_n$. How many possible distinct inequalities are there?

I assume this problem requires combinatorics , but I am not sure how to apply them in this problem.

**Edit**: Maybe this problem can be related with coin arranging (point me if I am wrong)

First of all , we can arrange coins (where order matters).But ,we will also allow for the coins to stack on top of each other.In the stacks (There can be multiple stacks) , order doesn't matter.Stacks will be represented with parenthesis.

For $1$ coin , there is $1$ way to arrange them.

1. $1$ $[x_1]$

For $2$ coins , there are $3$ ways to arrange them.

1. $12$ $[x_1 < x_2]$
2. $21$ $[x_1 > x_2]$
3. $(12)$ $[x_1 = x_2]$

For $3$ coins , there are $13$ ways to arrange them.

1. $123$ $[x_1 < x_2,x_2 < x_3,x_3 > x_1]$
2. $132$ $[x_1 < x_2,x_2 > x_3,x_3 > x_1]$
3. $213$ $[x_1 > x_2,x_2 < x_3,x_3 > x_1]$
4. $231$ $[x_1 > x_2,x_2 < x_3,x_3 < x_1]$
5. $312$ $[x_1 < x_2,x_2 > x_3,x_3 < x_1]$
6. $321$ $[x_1 > x_2,x_2 > x_3,x_3 < x_1]$
7. $(12)3$ $[x_1 = x_2,x_2 < x_3,x_3 > x_1]$
8. $3(12)$ $[x_1 = x_2,x_2 > x_3,x_3 < x_1]$
9. $1(23)$ $[x_1 < x_2,x_2 = x_3,x_3 > x_1]$
10. $(23)1$ $[x_1 > x_2,x_2 = x_3,x_3 < x_1]$
11. $2(13)$ $[x_1 > x_2,x_2 < x_3,x_3 = x_1]$
12. $(13)2$ $[x_1 < x_2,x_2 > x_3,x_3 = x_1]$
13. $(123)$ $[x_1 = x_2,x_2 = x_3,x_3 = x_1]$

I thought of thinking of stacks as variables that are equal.And a variable being left/right to another variable corresponding to a varialbe less than/ greater than another variable.So my thought is..

number of ways to arrange $n$ coins = number of distinct inequalities for $n$ variables.(Hope this helps)

Comment: you need to define the possible inequalities between the n variables, are we only allowing inequalities of the form $x_i ><= x_j$ or can we also have things like $x_i > x_j + x_k$ ?

Comment: no , we are not allowing the second case.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_Bell_number, more detail at https://oeis.org/A000670

Comment: Do you count $a<b$ and $b>a$ as distinct inequalities or not ?

Comment: Your coin analogy is not helpful Why don't you write the inequalities explicitly in the case of three variables ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mike Earnest commented, these are [ordered Bell numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_Bell_number) or Fubini numbers, and [OEIS A000670](https://oeis.org/A000670) shows many ways to calculate them, though not a closed form.

My preference would be with a recursion, letting $f(n,k)$ be the number of orderings of $n$ variables involving $k$ distinct values. When you introduce the $n$th variable, you can

- either introduce it to an ordering of $n-1$ variables with $k$ distinct values by matching it to one of the existing distinct values
- or introduce it to an ordering of $n-1$ variables with $k-1$ distinct values by matching it to one of the $k$ gaps between, before or after the existing distinct values

So $$f(n,k)=k\big(f(n-1,k) + f(n-1,k-1)\big)$$

and you can start with $f(1,1)=1$ and $f(1,k)=0$ for $k\not=1$, or from $f(0,0)=1$ and $f(0,k)=0$ for $k\not=0$.

You then get a table like this

$$\begin{matrix}
 & k& 0& 1& 2& 3& 4& 5& 6& 7& 8& & \text{Sum}\\
n& & & & & & & & & & & & \\
0& & 1& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& & 0\\
1& & 0& 1& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& & 1\\
2& & 0& 1& 2& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& & 3\\
3& & 0& 1& 6& 6& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& & 13\\
4& & 0& 1& 14& 36& 24& 0& 0& 0& 0& & 75\\
5& & 0& 1& 30& 150& 240& 120& 0& 0& 0& & 541\\
6& & 0& 1& 62& 540& 1560& 1800& 720& 0& 0& & 4683\\
7& & 0& 1& 126& 1806& 8400& 16800& 15120& 5040& 0& & 47293\\
8& & 0& 1& 254& 5796& 40824& 126000& 191520& 141120& 40320& & 545835\\
\end{matrix}$$

with the final column giving the result you want

Comment: I have also read that wiki article according to the suggestion of @Mike_Earnest.But I couldn't really understand how ordered bell numbers relate to such a problem (due to my lack of number theory and combinatorics knowledge).I might have to study it more deeply.@Henry thanks for your response.

Comment: What you are counting are "weak orderings" so while the [Bell numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number) count possible equivalence relations or partitions of a set, the *ordered* Bell numbers also count how these partitions can be ordered

Answer (score -1):

To make an inequality, you need two of the variables and one of three operators, so $n (n-1) 3.$ Notice that the order of the variables matters, so you do **not** divide by two.

Comment: Then according to you $n=2$ should give $6$ inequalities?

Comment: @LightYagami Yes.

Comment: If I plug in n=2 , then I will get 6 inequalities. half of the 6 inequalities are copies of the other half. For example , x1 < x2 is the same as x2 > x1.

Comment: But clearly according to OP we have only $x<y$, $y<x$ and $x=y$. What are the other three?

Comment: @LightYagami The OP did not say anything about the variables being lexicographically ordered, so what's wrong with $y<x?$

Comment: @IgorRivin there is nothing wrong with $y<x$. If you meant $x>y$ was also a possibility then I said that OP didn't include it in the question so there were only $3$ possibilities, because $x>y$ and $y<x$ were considered the same by him.